# Should shared_ptr constructor arguments be passed by value

Tags: c++, constructor, pass-by-reference, move, pass-by-value

When I pass a `shared_ptr` to a constructor that copies that argument into a member `shared_ptr`, should this parameter be passed by value?

Example:

```
struct MyClass {
    MyClass(std::shared_ptr<MyDependency> dep) 
        : dep(dep)
    {}

    std::shared_ptr<MyDependency> dep;
};
```

If constructed with a temporary (`MyClass(std::make_shared<...>())`) the compiler should move the argument (once or twice?).

Is the compiler able to "auto" move `dep` to `dep`,
or should I use `: dep(std::move(dep))`?

If constructed with a lvalue the value will be copied (min. one times).

On the other hand, passing the `shared_ptr` by const-ref will always copy the pointer.

So should constructor arguments be passed by value if they will be directly copied into a member?

**Edit:** The parameter/member must be a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Doesn't clarify about constructor, but might still be interesting for reading: Herb Sutter's [GotW#91](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)...

Comment: Are you sure `shared_ptr` is needed here? There is no shared ownership in this example.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Yes, it is needed. The example is not the best one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The C++11 way of initializing data members from arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138376/the-c11-way-of-initializing-data-members-from-arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should shared_ptr constructor arguments be passed by value

If you intend to share ownershi i.e. you want to keep a copy: Yes, passing by value is the preferred way.

> If constructed with a temporary ... the compiler should move the argument (once or twice?).

First the argument is move constructed, then the member is initialized (see below). The construction of the argument may be elided in some cases.

> should I use `: dep(std::move(dep))`

Yes, you should. The argument has a name, and so it is an lvalue. To move construct the member, you need to have an rvalue.

Comment: OK, so we'd end up in possibly moving twice?

Comment: @Aconcagua yes. Maybe even likely twice. I'm starting to doubt about the possibility of elision.

Comment: Hm, the more I think about, copy elision *should* apply in case of `MyClass(std::make_shared())`, another matter, though, would be `MyClass(std::move(somePtr))`

Comment: @Aconcagua yes indeed. GCC seems to elide in the first case, but not the other.

Comment: In the case `MyClass(std::make_shared<MyDependecy>())` the compiler will ellide the copy. It should be construction+move.

But the case of passing an lvalue, the compiler will do a copy+move, which is worse than what we get if we pass by const-ref, that is one copy without a move.

Comment: @user2079303 The compiler can't ellide in the second case, because we def. want a copy of the object.

Comment: @johannes Moving is relatively cheap, in contrast to copying. So it is more interesting to compare moving twice vs. copying once...

Comment: Summary so far: three situations: By value: passing l-value: copy + move. Passing r-value: move + move, in cases where copy elision can occur: only one move. By reference: passing l-value: copy; passing r-value: copy (both cases).

Comment: @Aconcagua Then the single "by value" constructor performs better than the single "by const-ref". The most efficient solution would be the one you've mentioned, at the "cost" of writing 2 constructors.

Comment: @johannes correct. The overhead of using shared ownership, or even using just the use of dynamic allocation is so high, that I would not care about the minuscule cost of one extra move. Note that the overloading becomes unbearable when there are more than one member to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

My personal approach would be using two constructors:

```
struct MyClass
{
    MyClass(std::shared_ptr<MyDependency> const& dep) 
        : dep(dep)
    {}
    MyClass(std::shared_ptr<MyDependency>&& dep) 
        : dep(std::move(dep))
    {}

    std::shared_ptr<MyDependency> dep;
};
```

L-values being passed, with the outer pointer retaining ownership, are just copied once as normally, r-values still are only references and thus just moved only once.